# Database page is not working when pushing rails code to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, heroku-postgres, ruby-on-rails-7

These are the only logs I get when I try to access my database page that lists all objects. I moved sqlite to development only in gemfile and added pg gem to :production

Page error when I click db link:

[image: page error when I click database link]

The errors found in the Heroku logs

[image: the errors found in the heroku logs]

Comment: heroku run rails db:migrate ?

Comment: Don't include the log as an image, paste the relevant lines into the question.